# What to do with Git Changes .history files? (vscode)

Tags: git, rebase

I did a rebase of my branche, and now I see a lot of local (U) **.history files** in my vscode-git Changes.

I guess these are all the changes before the rebase.

**Should I commit them?** What do I need them for? Thanks

Comment: You should have .history in your .gitignore. Do NOT commit local history. See https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Global/VisualStudioCode.gitignore

Comment: Matt, thanks so much